# Using CSS3 animation, animation-fill-mode causes wrong element size

Tags: css, animation

I got a strange result when I try to use CSS3 animation. When I added **animation-fill-mode** to the "parent" <div>, after the animation was finished the width of the "child" <div> was incorrect (less then 100%). Could somebody tell me why this happens? If I delete this style, everything works fine.

```
<div id="parent" class="fadeInLeft" >
     <div id="child">   </div>
</div>

#parent {               
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color:blue;
            border: 1px solid red;
            margin:50px;               
        }

#child
        {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            border:1px solid black;
            z-index:10;                
        }

  .fadeInLeft {
            -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
            -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
            -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
            animation-name: fadeInLeft;

            -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
             animation-duration: 1s;
             -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
             animation-fill-mode: both;
}


   @-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


https://jsfiddle.net/7gy4b2op/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:blue;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:50px;
}

#child {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    z-index:10;
            
        }

.fadeInLeft {
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
     -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
     animation-name: fadeInLeft;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="fadeInLeft" >
    <div id="child">   </div>
</div>
```

do you mean the child is just a little larger than the parent? if so, add box-sizing:border-box; to your child

Comment: If you delete animation-fill-mode: both; you will see wich result I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct.

The child is 100% width of the parent that is positioned. Since you apply a transform to the parent, parent is positioned and it is the width used to calculate this 100%.

But, otherwise, it isn't and the child gets the width from body,

Try changing parent position to relative, for instance, you will get the same result (300px)

Comment: Thank you, I know about position: "relative". I have another issue, if I delete "animation-fill-mode" row I still get animation effect, but a child element has a <body> width and this is strange.